# Arc memory management

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have two controllers and first controller pushes the second one.
I was using the allocation of the instrument to check memory allocations and I found sometimes a peak occurs in the allocation graph. Following is the screenshot.
What is the reason of this? is this normal or this is kind of problem, may be leak? I use arc by the way.
I also used leaks to find any memory leaks but it didnot show any.

[image]

Comment: A memory leak would show an ever increasing allocation graph. Whatever that spike was caused by, it was cleaned up properly, so not a memory leak.

Comment: Activate the time bounds (the little clocks with the shadowing in the top toolbar) and set the bounds to just fit around the memory spike.  Switch to "Created and Destroyed" under "Allocation Lifespan" on the left.  Change the "Statistics" drop down to "Call Trees" and activate the right panel (click the rightmost button above "View" in the top toolbar).  If you post a screenshot of that we'll be able to see your heaviest backtrace and get a better idea of what's using the memory.

Comment: If that's when the nib is loaded for the second controller, there are likely a bunch of ancillary objects created while it is loaded. And then they seem to be cleaned up.

Comment: I found the peak is because I repeatly created an UIButton in a loop like for (i=0 i<=10, i++){UIButton *button = [UIButton alloc]init]}
It seems that the buttons were not released soon enough. Although they were released in the end, I came up with the question that if there are 50+ or even more like hundreds of buttons, then this would crash the memory?